# Determining the height of a child VC's content from the container VC, and using it to size the container vc?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, childviewcontroller

I have a container view controller that can hold any generic ViewController. If I use a stack view, or any other view (without a scroll view), I can accurately calculate the size in my container initializer using the following:

```
let targetSize = CGSize(width: contentVC.view.bounds.width)
let preferredSize = contentViewcontroller.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)
self.containerHeight = preferredSize.height
```

However, this stops working once I'm dealing with a table view inside the child vc. The height is returned as zero. What's the best way to handle it without having to do much / any work on the child vc side?

NOTE: I'm using auto layout (SnapKit), to pin and layout my views.

Comment: A table view has no intrinsic size, so the question makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, but it has a content size. I've managed to get it to layout properly by using a protocol which provides the container with a height property. I can essentially set it to tableView.contentSize.height in the child VC and everything works. What I'd really like is to have the child vc update the container vc if there's a change (an item in the table view is removed). Trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: What happens if you have 50 rows in your "child VC" table view? Will your container height work if the table view's contentSize.height is, say, 3000?

Comment: Hhaha good question right now we aren't really accounting for that since we don't expect more than say 3-5 rows, but ideally the container view (drawer) would just mimic Uber's behavior of going full screen.

Comment: @KingPolygon - well, then, I'd recommend building your design and functionality with that in mind. Using a table view for 3-5 rows (which could just as easily be done with 3-5 instances of a custom view in a stack view, for example) is a very different prospect than "it might have 10, 20, 50 rows."

Comment: Fair point! Agreed

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to access UIView (UITableView) when it was only created and added as a subview, but it hasn't been drawn yet. You have to force draw it.

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

For the UIViewController you access it in `viewDidLoad()`, and it's the moment when the size is known